# Sum rows value if their IDs are in a defined range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this table:

```
+----+-------+-------------------+
| ID | Value |       Date        |
+----+-------+-------------------+
| 1  | 8     | 12/10/2015 8:00am |
| 1  | 10    | 12/10/2015 8:30am |
| 1  | 5     | 12/10/2015 9:00am |
| 1  | 11    | 12/10/2015 9:30am |
| 2  | 8     | 12/10/2015 8:00am |
| 2  | 6     | 12/10/2015 8:30am |
| 2  | 8     | 12/10/2015 9:00am |
| 2  | 9     | 12/10/2015 9:30am |
+----+-------+-------------------+
etc.
```

Right now I have a query like this (simplified for clarity):

```
SELECT ID, MAX(Value), MIN(Date)
FROM Values
WHERE ID IN (1,2,3,8)
GROUP BY (DATEPART(MINUTE, Date) / 60), ID
ORDER BY ID, MIN(Date)
```

Which returns something like this:

```
+----+-------+-------------------+
| ID | Value |       Date        |
+----+-------+-------------------+
| 1  | 10    | 12/10/2015 8:00am |
| 1  | 11    | 12/10/2015 9:00am |
| 2  | 8     | 12/10/2015 8:00am |
| 2  | 9     | 12/10/2015 9:00am |
| 3  | 12    | 12/10/2015 8:00am |
| 3  | 6     | 12/10/2015 9:00am |
| 8  | 51    | 12/10/2015 8:00am |
| 8  | 58    | 12/10/2015 9:00am |
+----+-------+-------------------+
```

I need to calculate the sum of the Value field if, let's say, the ID is 1, 2 or 3.
I expect something like this:

```
+------------+-------+-------------------+
|  IDfield   | Value |       Date        |
+------------+-------+-------------------+
| IDstring1  | 30    | 12/10/2015 8:00am |
| IDstring1  | 26    | 12/10/2015 9:00am |
| IDstring2  | 51    | 12/10/2015 8:00am |
| IDstring2  | 58    | 12/10/2015 9:00am |
+------------+-------+-------------------+
```

Or, even better:

```
+--------+--------+-------------------+
| Value1 | Value2 |       Date        |
+--------+--------+-------------------+
| 30     | 51     | 12/10/2015 8:00am |
| 26     | 58     | 12/10/2015 9:00am |
+--------+--------+-------------------+
```

The IDs I am required to sum are static, so I guess I can go for one of these solutions, but I can't think of a way to do so.

I'll try to explain the expected result better:

**Value1** should contain the SUM of the Value field where ID IN (1, 2, 3), grouped by hour as I already done in my query
**Value2** should simply contain the Value field where ID = 8

*Edit: added source table example, corrected the current query (I forgot to put the aggregate MAX() to the field Value in the SELECT)*

*Edit #2: added better explanation*

Comment: Does that query really execute?

Comment: Well, I've tried to simplify it, I hope I didn't get something wrong in the process... but, well, the one I use executes just fine

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output (related to the sample data!) I do not understand, what you want. Even worse I cannot even understand the logic...

Comment: Check the links bellow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34177991/sql-server-rolling-percentage-help-based-on-condition https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34176429/sql-query-to-get-for-each-item-the-line-of-a-group-that-has-the-maximum-occurenc/34179065#34179065

Comment: As @Shnugo said, you got to add some explanation on the logic of your expected result.

Comment: With the results from your first table inserted in a `#temp`. Just use a window function. ex: `select id, sum(value) over (partition by id) as Value, Date from #myTable`

Comment: @AndreaDorsa - If you run the query you gave, this is what you get which is way off from your result. Please use this fiddle to give a proper example and explain the logic behind the expected result
[http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b9208/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b9208/1)

Comment: Your query returns a completely different result... Please explain the logic: Which values and which logic are used to get your Value1 and Value2?

Comment: I'm curious, just because this was sort of a riddle... Did I finally get your needs correctly?

Comment: Nearly... Actually in your answer you consider a single value per hour per ID, while I actually have more than one value and I need to select the MAX from every hour. But I must say you really helped me out a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I finally got what you want:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT, Value INT, Date DATETIME);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,10,'12/10/2015 8:00am')
,(1,11,'12/10/2015 9:00am')
,(2,8,'12/10/2015 8:00am')
,(2,9,'12/10/2015 9:00am')
,(3,12,'12/10/2015 8:00am')
,(3,6,'12/10/2015 9:00am')
,(8,51,'12/10/2015 8:00am')
,(8,58,'12/10/2015 9:00am');

WITH Values123 AS
(
    SELECT SUM(Value) AS Sum123,Date
    FROM @tbl
    WHERE ID IN(1,2,3)
    GROUP BY Date
)
SELECT Values123.Sum123
      ,(SELECT SUM(Value) FROM @tbl WHERE Date=Values123.Date AND ID=8)
      ,Values123.Date 
FROM Values123
```

Result

```
Sum123  Sum8    Date
30      51      2015-10-12 08:00:00.000
26      58      2015-10-12 09:00:00.000
```

Comment: Thanks, this brings me even closer to the perfect answer.

Answer (score 2):

Database : PostgreSql

Query :

```
select sum("Value") as Value1, date from "Values" where id in(1,2,3) group by date
Union ALL
select sum("Value") as Value1, date from "Values" where id=8 group by date
```

Comment: Why not simply skip your `UNION ALL` and instead do `where id in(1,2,3,8)`? (Not sure if that's the answer to the question though.)

Comment: This helped me very much, I didn't get it perfectly as I asked, but I figured out another way thanks to this.